# How to insert a blank column in between every column of a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying (using python pandas) to split columns of a dataframe imported from an excel file, and set a blank column in between each pair of columns, and can't seem to work it out.
Example for input df:

```
ABC
111
222
```

And output:

```
A  B  C
1  1  1
2  2  2
```

(the space meaning its a blank column)

The main goal is to then export the df to excel and have blank column in between each of the original columns.

Thank you!

Comment: what do you plan on doing with the blank files? are you trying to export to an excel and have empty columns? are you going to fill those columns? having an end goal in mind will greatly simplify this task

Comment: Split columns by character - `pd.DataFrame(df['ABC'].astype(str).apply(list).values.tolist())`

Comment: @ Anonymous Dodo yes the main goal is to export it to excel and have blank columns between the columns. added to description

Answer (score 0):

```
temp = StringIO("""  
ABC
111
222
""")

df = pd.read_csv(temp, sep='\s+',header=None)
```

---

```
df = df[0].str.split('',expand=True)[[1,0,2,4,3]]
df.columns = df.loc[0]

df.drop(0).reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Output**

```
   A    B    C
0  1    1    1
1  2    2    2
```